# conn.remote_ip in 127.0.0.1 in production

Tags: nginx, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this on my website in the internet:

```
def create(conn, %{"aaa" => aaa}) do
  ip_addr = conn.remote_ip # a tuple
  # ....
```

For some reason, in production -- in the internet -- an ip address is 127.0.0.1 when "create" is triggered. Why is that?

My website is behind nginx.

Comment: Do you have the line `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` from http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/serving-your-application-behind-a-proxy in your nginx config?

Comment: @Dogbert, thx, i'll check.

Comment: @Dogbert, it's set.

Comment: @Dogbert, any idea?

Comment: Not sure. Can you post the output of `IO.inspect(conn.req_headers)` when you're accessing the app from a different IP than the server?

Answer (score 1):

Try this plug:

```
defmodule PlugForwardedPeer do
  import Plug.Conn
  def init(_), do: []
  def call(conn,_) do
    case get_req_header(conn,"x-forwarded-for") do
      []->
        case get_req_header(conn,"forwarded") do
          []-> conn
          [header|_]->
            ips = for "for="<>quoted_ip<-String.split(header,~r/\s*,\s*/), ip=clean_ip(quoted_ip), !is_nil(ip), do: ip
            case ips do
              []->conn
              [ip|_]->%{conn|remote_ip: ip}
            end
        end
      [header|_]->
        ips = for quoted_ip<-String.split(header,~r/\s*,\s*/), ip=clean_ip(quoted_ip), !is_nil(ip), do: ip
        case ips do
          []->conn
          [ip|_]->%{conn|remote_ip: ip}
        end
    end
  end
  def clean_ip(maybe_quoted_ip) do
    maybe_ip = maybe_quoted_ip |> String.strip(?") |> String.rstrip(?]) |> String.lstrip(?[)
    case :inet_parse.address('#{maybe_ip}') do
      {:ok,ip}->ip
      _->nil
    end
  end
end
```

Usage - like any other plug, add `plug PlugForwardedPeer` in place (e.g. in a controller)